# How to add additional SDK versions to .NET Docker image

Tags: docker, dotnet-sdk

I use Docker to build my .NET apps, using a [base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/) provided by Microsoft ([mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/d68460ceab4fe635d95a28bfca410db1a1d57caa/3.1/sdk/buster/amd64/Dockerfile)).

In addition to .NET Core SDK 3.1, I also need .NET Core SDK 2.2 inside the same container.

How can I extend the base image and install .NET Core SDK 2.2, without breaking the version in the base image? I noticed that Microsoft does not use a package manager to install .NET in the base image.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71311201/1887056