# Docker image with both dotnet sdk2 and sdk 3.1

Tags: .net, docker

Is there a docker image available with both dotnet sdk2 and sdk 3.1

I tried installing dotnet sdk2 inside sdk3.1 dotnet docker image and vice versa, but nothing worked. My requirement is I wanted to have a docker image with both dotnet2 & 3.1 sdk

Comment: Can you help us understand why you want a docker image with both SDKs? What are you trying to do? Are you aware that newer SDKs are generally backwards compatible and can be used to build applications for older .NET (Core) releases too?

Comment: Which base image were you trying to install the two SDK's onto? And can you share your Docker file or explain how you tried to install both.

Comment: @mdisibio mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-focal - is the docker image used. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux - Follow the procedure in the documentation but none of them worked!

Comment: @omajid I'm trying to build .net application using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-focal` - docker image used. Below is the error log: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version   The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.9' was not found.     - The following frameworks were found:         3.1.16 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

If its backward compatible then the error shouldn’t be seen right?

Comment: You still haven't told us why you want to do this. What's your use case. Can you also share your Dockerfile? You can use a single SDK image to build for multiple runtimes. But you must run your application using the runtime specific container. This should be easily doable using multi-stage builds.

Comment: @omajid I don't think the 'why' is that important. It's a legitimate environment that exists on many workstations organically as new sdk releases are installed by developers.

Comment: One option might be to setup a vanillia linux docker image, say Debian, get to the command line while running the container, and then install the two sdk's, starting with the lower version. If successful, save the container as your desired image. [Hanselman Side-by-Side on Linux](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/side-by-side-user-scoped-net-core-installations-on-linux-with-dotnetinstallsh)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71311201/1887056

Answer (score 0):

I have done this my own way previously, but when V2022 enterprise has just handled doing this for me (for dotnet core 6 and 7), so I thought I'd post that solution for you:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 as runtime6.0
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
# Copy .NET Core 6.0 runtime from the 6.0 image
COPY --from=runtime6.0 /usr/share/dotnet/host /usr/share/dotnet/host
COPY --from=runtime6.0 /usr/share/dotnet/shared /usr/share/dotnet/shared
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["InitialProcessingIsolated/InitialProcessIsolated.csproj", "InitialProcessingIsolated/"]
COPY ...... all my other projects, on a variety of frameworks
COPY ["FunctionsCommon/FunctionsCommon.csproj", "FunctionsCommon/"]
RUN dotnet restore "InitialProcessingIsolated/InitialProcessIsolated.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/InitialProcessingIsolated"
RUN dotnet build "InitialProcessIsolated.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "InitialProcessIsolated.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

When I've done it my self I've downloaded (with curl) and run (with CMD) the installer for dotnet, though in that case I was installing dotnet in a different base container. That also worked, though I omitted the nice multi-stage build for the sake of my sanity and just copied the compiled binaries in